# Moq not matching (simple) setup

Tags: c#-4.0, moq

I'm new to Moq, and having what seems to be a silly problem.
If I perform the setup based on a loop it iwll not match, but if I do the "identicatal" setup by hand I do get a match.

I am using Moq 4.0.10827, from NuGet

My interface being mocked is simple:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string GetValue(string input);
}
```

The test-entire program is below.
The expected output is identical for both methods, but "Foo" is not printed for Version2()

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Version1();
        Console.WriteLine("---------");
        Version2();
        Console.WriteLine("---------");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Version1()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();

        mock.Setup(x => x.GetValue(It.Is<string>(s => s == "Foo"))).Returns("Foo");
        mock.Setup(x => x.GetValue(It.Is<string>(s => s == "Bar"))).Returns("Bar");

        IMyInterface obj = mock.Object;

        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetValue("Foo"));
        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetValue("Bar"));
    }

    private static void Version2()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();

        string[] keys = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" };

        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            mock.Setup(x => x.GetValue(It.Is<string>(s => s == key))).Returns(key);
        }

        IMyInterface obj = mock.Object;

        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetValue("Foo")); // Does not match anything
        Console.WriteLine(obj.GetValue("Bar"));            
    }
}
```

I take it I am missing something.. but what ?

**Program output:**

```
Foo
Bar
---------

Bar
---------
```

Edit: Output from program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more generic way, this setup alone will let you return what you get from the parameter.

```
mock.Setup(item => item.GetValue(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string input) => input);
```

By using `It.Is<string>(s => s == "Bar")` you are probably overwriting first predicate. Try to change the order or string and check it behaves that way.

If you want to check values seperetely, you can do something like this

```
mock.Setup(item => item.GetValue("Foo")).Returns("Foo");
mock.Setup(item => item.GetValue("Bar")).Returns("Bar");
```

In a loop:

```
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    mock.Setup(x => x.GetValue(key)).Returns(key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This post is a somewhat simplification of what I am trying to achieve. I reduced it to the simpelst case where I could reproduce the behaviour. In reality, I have a service that returns an object based on the input, so a general "return identity" is not sufficient :/

Comment: Yeah, It's only the item from the last iteration which seems to be present. Isnt what you suggest what I did in Version1? In either case,  I dont understand why the second doesnt work.

Comment: Yes and no. Performing the setup w/o the loop will result in the invocations matching the setup, but I "need" the loop/predicate way to work. I updated the OP with program output

Comment: You can use this method in a loop. Predicate within loop will not work, because each iteration will overwrite old predicates. See the updated code.

Comment: Works perfectly. Didn't get the predicate overwrite thing at first. Thank you. (Can't upvote due to lack of reputation)

Comment: No, when you call the function with the value no predicates are kept.It just stores what parameters it's called with and it's return value. Predicate usage provides a way to make sure methods is called with only that value for given type.

Answer (score 0):

@Ufuk is correct. To clarify, this has nothing to do with Moq. It's the classic "Access to modified closure" issue (that's the warning message [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) gives for it).

For example:

```
void Main()
{
    var actions = new List<Func<string, bool>>();

    string[] keys = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" };

    foreach (string key in keys)
    {
        actions.Add(s => s == key);
    }

    foreach (var action in actions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is Foo: " + action("Foo"));
        Console.WriteLine("Is Bar: " + action("Bar"));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Is Foo: False
Is Bar: True

Is Foo: False
Is Bar: True
```

See [Jon Skeet's answer to C# Captured Variable In Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271447/161457) and Eric Lippert's [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).